# Mental Illness and the bardo and rebirth

Tags: rebirth, bardo

I'm wondering if mental illness is carried over into the space between lives and then subsequently to the next birth?

Comment: Are  you looking for answers based on personal experience, or based on references to doctrine? :-) You're asking about Tibetan Buddhism, specifically, I presume -- I think that "bardo" is Tibetan, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong view can cause long repetition of bad existences, yes. So look always to straighten [right view](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2106.msg9309.html#msg9309). to learn about what is right view and to stop ponder around about kamma, since such is one cause of getting "crazy". Beest right here and now!

*(Its not given for your trades, stacks and to maintain exchanges, but as a tiny emergency exit out of the wheel you are, in if wishing so.)*